# XSL Nested For-Each

Tags: xml, xslt

I've seen this thread elsewhere, so I apologize for cross-posting but I haven't been able to suss out the answer I need there. I have an XML document and I'm trying to right an XSL that will iterate over each item and then over particular nested nodes. As you can see below the catalog has multiple  nodes. I want my XSL to give the appropraite values for each of them.

Here is the XML:

```
<report>
<title>Template</title>
<dateCreated>2016-04-18T09:22:10</dateCreated>
<dateFormat>mm/dd/yyyy</dateFormat>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>25787</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1935</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="10">Durant, Will, 1885-

</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="14">The story of 

civilization.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>901 DUR V. 02</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>20</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2005-04-26</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002498655</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
<call>
<callNumber>901 DUR V. 03</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>26</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2003-12-11</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001393147</itemID>
<location>TRACKING</location>
</item>
</call>
<call>
<callNumber>901 DUR V. 05</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>6</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2009-05-15</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001942588</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
<call>
<callNumber>901 DUR V. 06</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>5</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2007-04-01</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001393089</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
<call>
<callNumber>901 DUR V. 07</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>7</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2009-10-22</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001393261</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
<call>
<callNumber>901 DUR V. 08</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>9</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2007-04-01</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002722609</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
<call>
<callNumber>901 DUR V. 10</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>3</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2004-07-28</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001942521</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
<call>
<callNumber>901 DUR V. 11</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>8</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2005-10-15</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001392743</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>49172</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>2002</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Gaddis, John 

Lewis.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="14">The landscape of history : how 

historians map the past / John Lewis Gaddis.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>901 GAD</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>9</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2009-05-14</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002542346</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>33197</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1946</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="10">Toynbee, Arnold 

Joseph, 1889-1975.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="12">A study of history / by Arnold 

J. Toynbee...Abridgement of volumes I-      by D. C. Somervell.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>901 TOY V. 02</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>2</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>1</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>1</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2012-01-04</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001463882</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>40301</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1965</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="10">Bernal, John Desmond, 

1901-</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Science in history [by] J.D. 

Bernal.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>901.9 BER</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>13</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2010-02-21</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407000449676</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>41847</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1972</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="10">Laver, James, 1899-

</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="14">The age of illusion: manners 

and morals 1750-1848.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>901.933 LAV</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>11</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2007-09-14</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407000450450</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>90504</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>2000</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Aron, Paul, 1956-

</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Unsolved mysteries of history : 

and eye-opening investigation into the most baffling events of all time / 

Paul Aron.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>902 ARO</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>31</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>1</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>1</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2012-05-16</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002294096</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>70904</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1999</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="00">Danger! : true stories of 

trouble and survival / collected and edited by James O'Reilly, Larry 

Habegger, and Sean O'Reilly.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>904 DAN</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>17</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>1</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>1</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2010-12-16</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002017182</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>3523</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1965</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="10">Brinton, Crane, 1898

-1968.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="14">The anatomy of revolution [by] 

Crane Brinton.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>904.7 BRI</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>9</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>1</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>1</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>1</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>1</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2011-06-14</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407000111581</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>94781</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1999</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Parenti, Michael, 

1933-</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">History as mystery / by Michael 

Parenti.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>907.2 PAR</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>27</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2011-07-01</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002189304</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>17535</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1996</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Almond, 

Mark.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Revolution : 500 years of 

struggle for change / Mark Almond.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>909 ALM</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>25</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>2</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>1</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>2</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>1</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2012-04-09</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001885282</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>35512</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1994</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Boorstin, Daniel J. 

(Daniel Joseph), 1914-</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Cleopatra's nose : essays on 

the unexpected / by Daniel J. Boorstin ; edited by Ruth F. 

Boorstin.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>909 BOO</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>18</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2010-04-01</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001625555</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>58912</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1994</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Braudel, 

Fernand.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="12">A history of civilizations / 

Fernand Braudel ; translated by Richard Mayne.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>909 BRA</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>42</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>2</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>2</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2012-05-11</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001101060</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>32441</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>2001</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Durant, Will, 1885-

</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Heroes of history : a brief 

history of civilization from ancient times to the dawn of the modern age / 

Will Durant.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>909 DUR</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>35</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>2</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>2</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2012-02-11</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002427472</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>49356</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>2001</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Evans, Colin, 1948-

</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Great feuds in history : ten of 

the liveliest disputes ever / Colin Evans.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>909 EVA</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>43</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2011-03-26</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002381778</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>13409</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1977</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="10">Greer, Thomas 

H.</marcEntry>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="12">A brief history of Western man 

/ Thomas H. Greer.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>909 GRE</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>15</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>2</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>1</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>2</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>1</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2012-03-13</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407000651743</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>62035</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1992</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="02">A History of civilization : 

prehistory to the present / Robin W. Winks ... [et al.].</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>909 HIS</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>50</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2010-02-08</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407001370392</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>93890</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1987</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="12">A history of private life / 

Philippe Aries and Georges Duby, general editors.</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>909 HIS V. 03</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>7</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>1</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>1</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2012-01-07</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002563847</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
<call>
<callNumber>909 HIS V. 04</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>8</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>1</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>1</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>1</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>1</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2012-03-18</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002563904</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
<call>
<callNumber>909 HIS V. 05</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>2</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>0</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>0</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2008-02-02</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002564381</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<catalogKey>100062</catalogKey>
<yearOfPublication>1998</yearOfPublication>
<marc>
<marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="04">The Life millennium : the 100 

most important events &amp; people of the past 1,000 years / [editor, 

Robert Friedman].</marcEntry>
</marc>
<call>
<callNumber>909 LIF</callNumber>
<item>
<numberOfCharges>0</numberOfCharges>
<numberOfBills>0</numberOfBills>
<numberOfCopyHolds>0</numberOfCopyHolds>
<totalCharges>22</totalCharges>
<inhouseCharges>0</inhouseCharges>
<totalCheckouts>1</totalCheckouts>
<totalRenewals>0</totalRenewals>
<intervalCheckouts>1</intervalCheckouts>
<intervalRenewals>0</intervalRenewals>
<intervalStartDate></intervalStartDate>
<recirculate>YES</recirculate>
<dateLastUsed>2012-02-08</dateLastUsed>
<isReserveItem>false</isReserveItem>
<copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
<itemID>33407002620340</itemID>
<location>NONFICTION</location>
</item>
</call>
</catalog>

</report>
```

And my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Weeding Report</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th style="text-align:left">Title1</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Author</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Pub Year</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">CallNumber</th>


    <th style="text-align:left">Charges</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Last Check Out</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Barcode</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Location</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="report/catalog">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Title']"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Personal 

Author']"/></td>


    <td><xsl:value-of select="yearOfPublication"/></td>
      <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="call">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="callNumber"/></td>


    <td><xsl:value-of select="item/totalCharges"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="item/dateLastUsed"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="item/itemID"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="item/location"/></td>

      </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. It seems that each `call` contains exactly one `item` - so you only need to create table row for each `call` and select the data you want to display in the table cells. -- P.S. Your XSLT is confusing, as it refers to many nodes that do not exist in the source XML. -- Seeing the expected result would be helpful, too.

Comment: Are those hyphens (`-`) to the left of `<marc>`, `<call>`, and `<item>` actually in the XML?

Comment: My final result would have rows for each <callNumber>. And each row would have the CallNumber, Title, Author, Publication Year, Charges, Last Check Out, Barcode, Location.

Comment: Your XSLT refers to `report/catalog`. Does your actual XML have multiple `catalog` elements which you want to display to? It would help if you amended your question to show your expected output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Weeding Report</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <!-- header -->
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th style="text-align:left">Title1</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Author</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Pub Year</th>

                    <th style="text-align:left">CallNumber</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Charges</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Last Check Out</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Barcode</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Location</th>
                </tr>

                <xsl:variable name="common">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Title']"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Personal Author']"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="yearOfPublication"/></td>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:for-each select="call">
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$common"/>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="callNumber"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="item/totalCharges"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="item/dateLastUsed"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="item/itemID"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="item/location"/></td>

                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, this would produce:

[image]

I am not sure why you need to repeat the first three cells for every row.

---

### Edit:

To fit your edited format, try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/report">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Weeding Report</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th style="text-align:left">Title1</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Author</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Pub Year</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">CallNumber</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Charges</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Last Check Out</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Barcode</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Location</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="catalog">
                    <xsl:variable name="common">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Title']"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="marc/marcEntry[@label='Personal Author']"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="yearOfPublication"/></td>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:for-each select="call">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$common"/>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="callNumber"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="item/totalCharges"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="item/dateLastUsed"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="item/itemID"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="item/location"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It was requested that I have a new row for each individual item. That's the right output but when I copy/paste it I don't get the same results. I edited the original XML (there are more "catalog" entries). I'm going to try to figure it out, but if you have a moment to help me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This is perfect. I'm sorry I can only upvote you once.